Can I disassemble start4.elf file?
I am a student studying with the Raspberry Pi 4.
I would like to learn about the embedded boot process, and I want to disassemble the startup4.elf file, but I was unable to do so with objdump or the GCC disassemble tool.
I understand that it uses the ISA of the Videocore VII GPU, and I am wondering if there is an official disassemble tool for this.
Or is there another efficient disassemble tool available?
Thanks for your helps!

Since it's closed source and proprietary, there is very unlikely to be an "official disassembler".  Possibly the reason you had trouble with this is it is not actually ARM code (although I think you know this vs. the GPU ISA): https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=97358

Some clues can be found here too https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=314022
